# Google Places Photo Request returning undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-photos

I have a horizontal scroll bar, that appears on the map, whenever particular venues are requested via Google Places and markers are placed.

My idea, is to have this horizontal scroll bar display a picture of each returned venue using Google places Photo request. However, the .getUrl() method that Google advises to use, is returning me an **'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'**; although I do receive an array of Objects and each Object has an array of photos.

Here is a part of my code:

```
for (var i = 0, place; place = venueData[i]; i++) {
        if (place.photos) {
            var photo = place.photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 100, 'maxHeight': 100 });
            $('.venues-display').append('<li><div class = venue-picture><img src='+photo+'></div></li>')
        }
        else {
          $('.venues-display').append('<li><div class = venue-picture><img src='+ place.icon + '></div></li>') 
        }
```

The error that I get points to the line with getUrl().

**venueData variable** - is the array of Objects that is returned back from Google Places Text Search.

**'.venues-display'** - is the class name of my scroll bar.

I am a newbie..and getting desperate, because I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

Pleeease heeeelp

Comment: Your code looks okay to me. You may try inspecting the place.photo object, ex. alert(place.photo[0].getUrl) to be sure it returns an object. If not try alert(place.photo[0]).

Comment: Use  `if (place.photos.length)` instead of `if (place.photos)`

Comment: Thanks for replying, guys. I just discovered with printing out the photo objects in my console that they do not have the getUrl() method..maybe because I am requesting the venues using rails, and not google's JS methods for search. I've played around with Places library, including using google's JS methods for Place search, and this way a photo object does have a getUrl method and it works...Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The method .getUrl() only works with the Google Places Library (in other words if you call .PlaceServices), where you do not need to use your API key

```
new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
```

Otherwise, you need to use this piece of code for getting the photos:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?parameters
```

At least that's what I understood with reading through the Google docs and using different pieces of code for the same reason